# Add different image in each section-slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I am using the Metropolis theme in beamer and I need to add different images in each section. Of course, I also want to keep the progress bar as it is. 
I am using this code, unfortunately, it is not working.

```
       \documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{transparent}

\definecolor{darkmidnightblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}

\begin{document} 
\maketitle

    \begin{frame}{\textbf{1st frame example}} %several frames (slides) like this one
    In this lecture we will:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Introduce...
        \item Define ...
        \item Explore ...
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}  

%section 1 with image 1 I also need the image to be transparent
     \section{\textcolor{darkmidnightblue}{\textbf{Measuring Inequality}}}
       \transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{section_1_image.png}

    \begin{frame}{\textbf{2nd frame example}} %several frames (slides) like this one
    In this lecture we will:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}  

%section 2 with image 2 I also need the image to be transparent
     \section{\textcolor{darkmidnightblue}{\textbf{Measuring Poverty}}}
       \transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{section_2_image.png}

  \begin{frame}{\textbf{3rd frame example}} %several frames (slides) like this one
    In this lecture we will:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item d
        \item e
        \item f
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}  

%section 3 with image 3 I also need the image to be transparent
     \section{\textcolor{darkmidnightblue}{\textbf{the summary}}}
       \transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{section_2_image.png}

 \begin{frame}{\textbf{summary}}{}
    Today, we have:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Introduced...
        \item Defined ...
        \item Explored ...
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Please could you help?
Thank

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a complete MWE that starts at `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` that shows your problem but not more?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post.

Comment: If I add `\usetheme{metropolis}` I get an undefined colour error, and the default theme doesn't have a progress bar. That aside, should there be a single slide for each section showing the image, or do you intend to change some kind of logo for that section?

Comment: Sorry, but I am new to this platform. the edited version now should work. And yes, in each section, I want to add a new specific image, i.e. in section 1, I add image 1, and in section 2, I add a different image (image 2). Thank you.

Comment: It's no problem and thanks for providing the additional information. I still don't know whether you want a single slide with the image or the image on every slide of a section.

Comment: Thanks! I have 3 sections in the presentation, iI want to add different image on every slide of a section.

Comment: So I should have an image on every slide of a section. I mean by "a section" the section-page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, if the following solution is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% graphicx and xcolor are load by beamer
\usepackage{pgfplots}% it loads tikz too
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\themename}{\textbf{\textsc{metropolis}}\xspace}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{transparent}

\definecolor{darkmidnightblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.2, 0.4}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\section{\textcolor{darkmidnightblue}{\textbf{Measuring Inequality}}}
\transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}%{section_1_image.png}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\textbf{1st frame example}} %several frames (slides) like this one
    In this lecture we will:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Introduce...
        \item Define ...
        \item Explore ...
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\textbf{2nd frame example}} %several frames (slides) like this one
    In this lecture we will:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{\textcolor{darkmidnightblue}{\textbf{Measuring Poverty}}}
\transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}%{section_2_image.png}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\textbf{3rd frame example}} %several frames (slides) like this one
    In this lecture we will:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item d
        \item e
        \item f
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{\textcolor{darkmidnightblue}{\textbf{the summary}}}
       \transparent{0.4}\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-duck}%{section_2_image.png}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\textbf{summary}}{}
    Today, we have:
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Introduced...
        \item Defined ...
        \item Explored ...
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. This is what I am looking for.