# Beamer metropolis theme: How can I add a paragraph below the horizontal bar in section page?

Tags: beamer, overleaf, beamer-metropolis, section-titles

Below is the code from the metropolis theme that is responsible for formatting each section page appearing in the presentation:

```
\setbeamertemplate{section page}{
    \begin{center} % add center if missing
    \begin{minipage}{30em}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{section title}
    \usebeamerfont{section title}
    %\raggedright % comment out raggedright
    \centering % add centering here to center title
    \insertsectionhead\\[-1ex]
    \usebeamertemplate*{progress bar in section page}
    \par
    \ifx\insertsubsectionhead\@empty\else%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{subsection title}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection title}%
    \insertsubsectionhead
    \fi
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
    \par
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
}
```

The output so far is the section title followed by a horizontal progression bar. What I am trying to achieve is adding text in smaller font below the horizontal progression bar. Any ideas how to do it?

Example of how I want it to look like:

[image]

Comment: A sketch of the expected output would be useful. Could you please add one to your question? Also, will your presentation contain any subsections? Do you want to add the exact same text to all of your section pages or a different text for each section?

Comment: @leandriis I added a sketch of how the section page should look like. My presentation does not contain any subsections, and the text should be different in each of the sections.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539476/134144  may be helpful.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!